# New iOS 13 Modal Presentation: Presenting Controller Doesn't Move Down

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, uiviewcontroller, ios13

I have a weird behavior when presenting UIViewControllers modally in iOS 13. The new presentation style that I've seen all across iOS 13 looks like this:

*The presenting view controller appears behind the presented view controller. It is also shifted down to mimic a "stack"*

[image: The presenting view controller appears behind the presented view controller. It is also shifted down to mimic a "stack"]

Meanwhile, when presenting view controllers through my app, I keep getting this effect:

*The presenting view controller doesn't move at all when presenting a new view controller*

[image: The presenting view controller doesn't move at all when presenting a new view controller]

I use this code to present this view controller:

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tutorial") as! TutorialController
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
controller.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Here is my question:**
I'm wondering why this is happening and if there is a way to present view controllers in the normal iOS 13 style (with the presenting view controller moving back).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As a test, try commenting out the `controller.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical` and even the `controller.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet` (though the presentation style would be needed if this code is also run on an iPad).

Comment: I commented it out but it doesn’t change anything :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out the problem was my view controller hierarchy. I was able to fix it by making the presenting view controller the root view controller of my app. First I set the background controller as the root view controller by calling

```
window.rootViewController = self
```

and then using my previous code

```
let controller = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tutorial") as! TutorialController
controller.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
controller.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical
present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

I presented the view controller. Thanks to everyone who tried to help!

Comment: I am having the same problem. Where did you set the rootViewController flag? Right before the segue?

Comment: I set it when I presented the "background controller". Let's call them controllers 1, 2, and 3 to make things easier (1 being the furthest in the back, 2 being in the background behind 3, and 3 being the one in the front aka the Tutorial Controller). We are currently looking at controller 1. Instead of calling present() on controller 1 to present controller 2, I just set controller 2 as the root view controller. This basically gets rid of controller 1 and our window now only has controller 2 in its hierarchy. Now, you can present controller 3 normally by calling present() on controller 2.

Comment: Sure, that works for me but causes a variety of different problems like dissapearing status bar or animation cutting during segue, also I don't think it is safe. There has to be a better solution to this...

Comment: When do these problems occur? When you call the present() or when you set the root view controller? The disappearing status bar could be because the status bar is in black text and appears on a black background when the present() occurs causing it to blend in with the application’s background.

Comment: I present my view controller with a segue definied in IB. The status bar dissapears completely after setting the root view controller. Can you maybe show me how exactly do you set the root view controller in a safe way and where do you do this in code? I did in the "viewDidLoad" of the presented VC. That causes the animation cut and the status bar dissapears completely (not visible on white nor black)

Comment: I created a simple demo project. You can look at it over here: [github](https://github.com/CentrumGuy/Controller-Modal-Presentation.git). All of the logic is in Controller1.swift. Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You are the best. This doesn't help me unfortunatly - setting VC as root automaticaly makes that VC visible, with no transition/animation. Also the weird dissapearing status bar bug is still present in my project. Maybe Apple will figure this out...

Comment: you can animate the root view controller change by calling `let window = appDelegate.window!`, then calling `window.rootViewController = viewController` and finally: `UIView.transition(with: window, duration: 0.2, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {})`. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue can be resolved by using `vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen` if there is not UINavigationController , otherwise you can use these codes as follows:

```
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc) 
navigationController.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen 
present(vc, animated: true)
```

because With iOS 13 this is a new feature that Apple has changed the default presentation style of View Controllers to a modal sheet from fullscreen in iOS 12

Comment: .fullScreen makes it look like the old iOS 12 presentation where you can’t see the controller behind it at all. That is not what I’m going for.

Comment: @CentrumGuy,  you may see the link "https://medium.com/better-programming/ios-13-checklist-for-developers-ef47e413aad2", It was explained in details.

Comment: I know Apple changed the default presentation style in iOS 13. However, when I present my view controllers in my app the presenting controller doesn’t move like it does everywhere else on iOS 13. You can look at the difference between the first and second pictures in the way the presenting view controller is displayed behind the topmost view controller. I want to get mine to display like the first picture

Comment: I'm glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Programmatically:

```
let vc = UIViewController()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

From storyboard:

[image]

That's it. No need to play with root controller or window at all.

For reference, visit [this article](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e).

Answer (score 1):

iOS13: Let's say you have 3 view controllers: FirstVC, SecondVC, ThirdVC

FirstVC presents SecondVC with the below code:

```
let secondVC = SecondVC()
secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
firstVC.present(secondVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

SecondVC presents ThirdVC with the below code:

```
let thirdVC = ThirdVC()
secondVC.present(thirdVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Changing secondVC's modalPresentationStyle to `.currentContext` solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can change it in the Inspector Tool Bar. To Achieve it: head over to the fifth section of Inspector Tollbar then change the Presentation field to Full Screen.

Answer (score -1):

This should be the only property you need to set

```
presentedViewController.modalPresentationStyle = .automatic
```

Detailed in 
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/224/

Comment: Setting it to automatic doesn't appear to fix this issue

Comment: The view controller behind the foreground view controller is the one I call the "present" on. (The one you can kind of see behind the controller)

Comment: is it the root? you can check window.rootViewController